# ubuntu 16.04 desktop no launcher, no dash

Tags: unity

After a crash and restart, my Ubuntu 16.04  desktop environment doesn't work - no launcher, no dash, nothing except a wallpaper. I can drop in a terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T, and then I follow the steps marked as answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), that is

1. reinstall `compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. enable unity in `ccsm`

These steps above completed without error, however, problem persists. I also tried the following

```
export DISPLAY=:0   
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

However I got the following error from `dconf`:

> GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code17: Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header

The ubuntu runs in a virtualbox in a MacOS 10.10 host. This should not be the problem because the desktop works as expected if I login in as Guest. The problem must be that  something of my account is corrupted.  Any advice is appreciated.

**Update**

I finally fixed the problem after hours of trial-and-error. Here is the solution for me:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall unity
rm -r .Xauthority .ICEauthority .config/.compiz-1 .config/dconf
```

Comment: There are more different suggestions in the answers further below on that linked question. Please try them first as well.

Comment: Will you add the output of `df -v` to your question?  I'm thinking that the crash came from running out of space, and the lack of the desktop integrity the results of a lack of space.

Comment: @James: Still have space left. See the output `df -v` above.

Comment: Try doing this:`sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-unity-desktop`

Comment: @zakoda: apt not able to find the ubuntu-unity-desktop. Is the package  for ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: My bad, it should be just `unity`. Try now, by replacing the package name by `unity`

Comment: @zakoda, reinstalled `unity` but problem persists.

Comment: install the package `unity-tweak-tool` as I remember that it has options to explicitly hide launcher and side panel. Perhaps you installed some other application and accidentally hid it. You could try altering the settings through `unity-tweak-tool` to see if this is the effect of a superficial trigger or change of state due to some other application. Again, I'm guessing your problem, so it may or may not work. Worth a try as it won't cause any harm/changes to your system. Also sounds like it's a problem like this ^ as it is user specific.